# Java Symbol not found through javac weird error (Runs through Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

My project runs smoothly in Eclipse, no errors at all. I ran it through local tests (that are equal to the ones in an online mooshak contest) and all checks out. But when I sumbit it online, I get a CompileTimeError.

To try to locate the problem, I attempted to use javac in Main.java, and this happened:

```
javac -encoding US-ASCII Main.java
Main.java:8: error: package code does not exist
import code.*;
^
Main.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
        public static void addWords(Scanner in, LibSystem system, int wordCount)
 {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class LibSystem
  location: class Main
Main.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
         public static void searchWord(LibSystem system, String word) {
                                      ^
```

Other symbol errors follow for every reference to classes from my only package, which I fully import and the header of Main, for a total of 29 errors.

- Project

  - src

    - Main.java
    - code (package with all my other java files)

Comment: jar containing LibSystem class is not available for your online system

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :-
1.) make sure LibSystem class is in classpath.

2.)Compile java files in code folder using -d option. That will create directories with classes.

javac -d . code/*.java

3.) then compile your Main class.

javac Main.java